# JSON from SQL query with child level

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-json

I have a simple query in my database:

```
SELECT id, name FROM users FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('users')
```

This returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "John"}
        {"id": "2", "name": "Mike"}
    ]
}
```

I want to have the return with the following format:

```
{
    "users": {
        "list": [
            {"id": "1", "name": "John"}
            {"id": "2", "name": "Mike"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Can I do this on SQL level by simply changing the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try with this:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id varchar(1),
   [name] varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO users
   (id, [name])
VALUES
   ('1', 'John'),
   ('2', 'Mike')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT users = (SELECT id, name FROM users FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('list'))
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{"users":{"list":[{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Mike"}]}}
```